# Cancelling an Observable in RxJava

Tags: rx-java

I have an observable that is performing a download. However I want to cancel that observable when I click on a button.

How is that possible?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you provide some code as to what you tried already ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't really tell an observable to cancel a network request as RxJava has no knowledge of the code thats running inside of the Observable.  What you can do is use the `doOnUnsubscribe` to check whether the network request is still running and if it is cancel it, then just unsubscribe when you want to cancel.

Answer (score 2):

This should give you the general idea. The summary is to use `Observable.using()` and subscribe to the `Observable` with a `Subscriber` so you can call `subscriber.unsubscribe()` when the user clicks the button to cancel.

Here's an outline.

```
Subscriber<T> subscriber = ...;
Observable
    // create a stream from a socket and dispose of socket
    // appropriately
    .using(socketCreator(host, port, quietTimeoutMs),
           socketObservableFactory(charset), 
           socketDisposer(), true)
    // cannot ask host to slow down so buffer on
    // backpressure
   .onBackpressureBuffer()
   .subscriber(subscriber);
```

On clicking a button call:

```
subscriber.unsubscribe()
```

This will stop the observable stream and call `socketDisposer()` to stop the network activity.

You haven't specified what is the nature of your download (ftp, http, etc) but the answer doesn't really change because all of those transports will fit this pattern.

Comment: Yeah, the `using` is a good idea, but I'd probably make the button clicks reactive as well, and just use `Observable. ... ..takeUntil(button.clickedSource())` instead of using the subscriber.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had a Publish subject that was emitting items in a certain condition. In some condition I wanted to cancel it, So I added a sealed class that holds the state:

```
sealed class DelayedItem {
   object Ignore : DelayedItem()
   data class Handle(val text: String) : DelayedItem()
}
```

And my subscriber was bounced like that:

```
myPublishSubject
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .debounce(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .subscribe {
                if (it is DelayedItem.Handle)
                    handleItem(it)
            }
```

Hope it helps!