# How to implement cancel operation on rx observable?

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java2, dispose

I have long running operation on server and app has to show percent progress. But user has to have a possibility to stop operation at any time.

retrofit2 definition of server call:

```
interface FooRemoteService {
    @POST("/foos")
    fun postFoos(@Body foos: List<FooPojo>): Observable<Response<List<String>>
 }
```

And hire is a simplified version what I figure out.

1. disposable variable is defined in fragment

   `var disposable: Disposable? = null`
2. when start button is clicked app starts observable from iterable and shows progress and assigns value to disposable variable:

   startButton.setOnClickListener {

   ```
   disposable = Observable.fromIterable(chunkedList)
           .flatMap { fooRemoteService.postFoos(it) }
           .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
           .doOnDispose { Log.d("TAG", "end! due to dispose") }
           .subscribe(
                 { Log.d("TAG", "progress") }, 
                 { Log.e("TAG", it.message) }, 
                 { Log.d("TAG", "end!") }
            )
    }
   ```
3. when cancel button is clicked app tries to call dispose() on any object which is referred by disposable variable:

   cancelButton.setOnClickListener {
       disposable?.dispose()
       Log.d("TAG","dispose!")
   }

It works but I have a doubts: Is it good approach? using a variable to have access to operation which should be canceled? Is dispose() is correct method to cancel in this use case?

Comment: Maybe this answer can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33137849/2910520

Comment: call disposable.dispose() and yes it fine to dispose. also you can read up on LifeCyle at https://blog.danlew.net/2014/10/08/grokking-rxjava-part-4/

Comment: Just being curious, what's wrong with `disposable.dispose()`?

Comment: @jaychang0917 I just felt that should be more elegant way. I just expected a solution which after break a processing of observable elements call onComplite event. So dispose() doesn't do that so I feel anxiety that calling dispose() isn't a right solution.

Comment: if the process is cancelled, it seems doesn’t make sense that the oncomplete should be called as it is not completed.