# List of Singles, use only first successful result

Tags: multithreading, kotlin, concurrency, rx-java2

Suppose I have list of input parameters:

```
val array = arrayOf(input1, input2, ... inputN) // N is usually less than 10
```

I have to process this parameters by doing some heavy computations. So to optimize it I'm trying to run each computation in his own thread running concurrently with others. I'm using RxJava2 for it:

```
sealed class Result {
   object Success : Result()
   object NotFound : Result()
}

fun processArray(arr: Array<Input>): Single<Result> {
    val singles = arr.map { input ->
        Single.fromCallable { 
            val time = System.currentTimeMillis()
            val r = process(input) 

            log("$r, took ${System.currentTimeMillis() - time}ms")
            return@fromCallable r
        }
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
    }

    return Single.zip(singles) { results ->
        val r = results.map { it as Result }
            .firstOrNull { it is Result.Success }
            ?: Result.NotFound

        log("result is: $r")
        return@zip r
    }
} 

fun process(input: Input): Result
```

Everything works, but when I look at the logs I usually see the following:

```
NotFound, took 130ms
NotFound, took 300ms
Success, took 220ms
NotFound, took 78ms
NotFound, took 540ms
NotFound, took 256ms
result is Success
proccessing took 547ms
```

And this doesn't make sense as I only need first successful result to be returned. But this code will wait for all of them to complete even if it already have found `Result.Success` (As you can see from logs the overall time spent == 547ms because we were waiting for the item with `NotFound, took 540ms` to finish, but at the moment I got `Result.Success` I knew that the rest will be NotFound)

## So the question is:

**Is it possible to run multiple `Single.fromCallable()` and upon finding first successful result dispose the rest?**

Comment: There's select expression in kotlin coroutines, but I don't know much about RxJava that much, probably its not possible because it goes around callbacks.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33126112/cancelling-an-observable-in-rxjava

Comment: @AnimeshSahu thanks, but unfortunately we don't use coroutines on a project, and the link is not related for my problem :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can merge instead of zip, and then filter to get the 1st element of type Success, like this

```
sealed class Result {
    object Success : Result()
    object NotFound : Result()
}

fun processArray(arr: Array<Input>): Single<Result> {
    val singles = arr.map { input ->
        Single.fromCallable {
            val time = System.currentTimeMillis()
            val r = process(input)

            log("$r, took ${System.currentTimeMillis() - time}ms")
            return@fromCallable r
        }
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
    }

    return Single
        .merge(singles)
        .filter { it is Result.Success }
        .firstElement()
        .switchIfEmpty(Single.just(Result.NotFound))
}

fun process(input: Input): Result
```

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for!